# SSL on appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I read this page: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl
What I'm wondering: When you create a Google Apps for Work account to get a certificate, does the same user need to 'own' the Google Cloud Platform account where the appengine is running?

And who should be the 'owner' of Cloud DNS?

In many cases, the programmer is not part of the company, so he doesn't have a google apps user account. Or is sharing access of the Cloud Platform enough to get SSL.

Regards, Peter

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** GAE SSL on custom domains is about to break free of Google Apps, which may significantly change the context for your question and answer(s). See https://support.google.com/a/answer/2644334:

[image]

Currently the Google Apps SSL configs only map certificates to the custom domain URLs, regardless of those URLs being served by GAE apps or not, so app ownership identity shouldn't matter. But this needs to be done by a Google Apps Admin.

For now Google Apps Admins can still map custom domain URLs to GAE apps (unclear if they need to own the apps, the above note suggest they might not need to) - which will change after the migration to the Developer Console.

Both the Google Apps Admin or the GAE app owner can perform the app mapping to a custom domain URL (via the Apps Admin console or the Developer Console, respectively) provided they pass the [domain ownership verification](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60216) (the actual Cloud DNS `owner` doesn't matter technically).

Answer (score 0):

The page you read links to [a more detailed documentation for Google Apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2644334), where you can find this :

> To add your application to the Google Apps account, the account
>   administrator’s sign-in account (email address) should be an owner of
>   the app. This is set in the Google Cloud Platform documentation under
>   Permissions.

So the admin user who enables SSL on Google Apps must also be an owner of the Google Cloud Platform project.

Who owns the DNS settings (be it Google Cloud DNS or any other DNS service) is independent : it doesn't have to be the same person.